# "display: none" smooth animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in the jsfiddle you will find a header
with a search icon which when pressed, will make a search bar appear under the header. but the problem is that it appears instantly. I want the header to smoothly expand and the search bar to fade in. I tried but couldn't get it to work.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/HussamAlhassan/zwg0drne/15/

here's the code:
html:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/brands.css" integrity="sha384-IiIL1/ODJBRTrDTFk/pW8j0DUI5/z9m1KYsTm/RjZTNV8RHLGZXkUDwgRRbbQ+Jh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-v2Tw72dyUXeU3y4aM2Y0tBJQkGfplr39mxZqlTBDUZAb9BGoC40+rdFCG0m10lXk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384-q3jl8XQu1OpdLgGFvNRnPdj5VIlCvgsDQTQB6owSOHWlAurxul7f+JpUOVdAiJ5P" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; box-shadow: 0px 1px grey; transition: .4s ease-in-out;" id="headershell">
  <div id="header">

    <div id="searchicondiv">
      <i class="fas fa-search searchicon"></i>
    </div>

    <div id="namediv">
      <h1 id="name">Header</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="logindiv">
      <a href="#">
        <h2 id="login">Login</h2>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="hiddensearch" class="Hidden" style=" background-color: black;">
    <div style="width: 100%;">
      <input id="search" placeholder="Search..">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
div#header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

div#header #name {
  color: white;
  font-family: orbitron;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

div#header #login {
  color: white;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  padding: 0px;
}

div#headershell .searchicon {
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

div#headershell .searchicon:hover,
#login:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

div#namediv {
  float: left;
  width: 33.4%;
}

div#searchicondiv {
  width: 33.3%;
  margin: auto;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

div#logindiv {
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
}

div#hiddensearch {
  z-index: 100;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

div#hiddensearch #search {
  padding: .4em;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: -5%;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border: 2px white solid;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

div#hiddensearch #search:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px black solid;
  outline-width: 0px;
}

.headernotHidden {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.notHidden {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.Hidden {
  display: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // jQuery methods go here...

  $(".searchicon").click(function hidesearch() {
    if ($("#hiddensearch").hasClass("Hidden")) {
      $("#hiddensearch").removeClass("Hidden");
      $("#hiddensearch").addClass("notHidden");

      $(".searchicon").removeClass("fa-search");
      $(".searchicon").addClass("fa-times");

      $("#headershell").addClass("headershellHidden");

    } else {
      $("#hiddensearch").removeClass("notHidden");
      $("#hiddensearch").addClass("Hidden");

      $(".searchicon").removeClass("fa-times");
      $(".searchicon").addClass("fa-search");

      $("#headershell").removeClass("headershellHidden");
    }
  })


});
```

edit: solutions that consist of setting the opacity to 0 wont work because you can still click on the input which isnt what i want

Comment: What's `onclick="$hidesearch"`?

Comment: sorry that's extra unused code from before

Comment: use length: 0 and transition length property. alobng with dispaly none

Comment: could you edit the jsfiddle for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of the jQuery methods for animation listed below.

```
.slideUp()
.slideDown()
.fadeIn()
.fadeOut()
.slideToggle()
```

Here you go. I have used `slideToggle()` method in following fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/zwg0drne/27/

You were over-engineering and writing too many lines to achieve a simple thing. Please note that I have also made changes in CSS.

Edit: updated fiddle link to toggle search icon with close icon as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `display: none`, use `opacity: 0;` on the CSS for `.Hidden`

https://jsfiddle.net/k1yg95gk/2/

Comment: that sort of works but it the header still doesn't expand like I want it to.

Comment: and also, there's this weird line that almost seems like a border for the div but i cant seem to be able to get rid of it

Comment: @Husam_alhassan - using @Johannes ' jsfiddle, you can add `margin-top: 0px;` to `.notHidden` and add `margin-top: -20px;` to `.Hidden` and it will look like it's sliding downward while fading in. The "weird line" below the header is the `box-shadow` you have added inline in the html for `#headershell` ... Remove that and it goes away.

Comment: @Hussam_alhassan That "weird line" is the box-shadow of the container element (`#headershell`), so you should erase the box-shadow from that (directly in the HTML code). And for an up/down effect you can also add `height: 0` to the `.hidden` class, so the height gets transitioned/animated

Comment: I forgot to add the link the the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k1yg95gk/17/

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are using jQuery.
Instead of using display: none; you can use the jQuery .hide() and .show().

You can use it this way :

```
$(selector).hide(speed, callback);

$(selector).show(speed, callback);
```

or even simpler, with the .toggle(), like this :

```
$(selector).toggle(speed, callback);
```

All documentations are here :

[For hide();](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

[For show();](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

[For toggle();](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

You'll just have to handle the speed as you wish.

**EDIT**

Edited JSFiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/zwg0drne/30/

If the animation is not okay for you, you can use `toggleClass();` with the animation you want in this CSS class (on the display, the height, the width.. whatever you want, with a transition speed).

Documentation here :
[toggleClass() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)